# xslt aggregation sum

Tags: xslt

I want do some sum of the values and return it as a row or column with the data.

taking the below xml as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<root>

   <default0>


    <Group>
      <groupEntry>
        <Day>Mon</Day>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Number>-3</Number>
      </groupEntry>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <groupEntry>
        <Day>Tue</Day>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Number>4</Number>
      </groupEntry>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <groupEntry>
        <Day>Tue</Day>
        <ID>444</ID>
        <Number>5</Number>
      </groupEntry>
      <Breakdown>
        <Details>
          <Day>Tue</Day>
          <ID>444</ID>
          <Number>-3</Number>
        </Details>
        <Details>
          <Day>Tue</Day>
          <ID>444</ID>
          <Number>8</Number>
        </Details>
      </Breakdown>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <groupEntry>
        <Day>Fri</Day>
        <ID>333</ID>
        <Number>-3</Number>
      </groupEntry>
    </Group>


  </default0>

</root>
```

My below xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:text>ID,Day,Number</xsl:text>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="groupEntry|Details">




      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>


  </xsl:template>




  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns this result:

```
ID,Day,Number 
111,Mon,-3 
222,Tue,4 
444,Tue,5 
444,Tue,-3 
444,Tue,8 
333,Fri,-3
```

However I want to get the total number by Day and report it in the result as either of the below 2 options

1. create 1 summary row like:

   ```
     ID,Day,Number
     Mon,Mon,-3
     111,Mon,-3
     Tue,Tue,9
     222,Tue,4
     444,Tue,5
     444,Tue,-3
     444,Tue,8
     Fri,Fri,-3
     333,Fri,-3
   ```
2. create an extra column:

   ```
     ID,Day,Number,TotalNumber

     111,Mon,-3,-3
     222,Tue,4,9
     444,Tue,5,9
     444,Tue,-3,9
     444,Tue,8,9
     333,Fri,-3,-3
   ```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Isn't the total for **Tue** 14, and not 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either option, you would probably need to define a key to group the elements by **Day**

```
<xsl:key name="days" match="groupEntry|Details" use="Day"/>
```

Then you can just add your extra column like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('days', Day)/Number)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT for the first option

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="days" match="groupEntry|Details" use="Day"/>

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>ID,Day,Number,TotalNumber</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="groupEntry|Details">
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('days', Day)/Number)"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following results

```
ID,Day,Number,TotalNumber
111,Mon,-3,-3
222,Tue,4,14
444,Tue,5,14
444,Tue,-3,14
444,Tue,8,14
333,Fri,-3,-3
```

In the second option, you would want to add a total line for the first occurrence of a particular **Day**. You can do this by checking if the current element is the first element in the key for that day

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('days', Day)[1])">
```

Here is the XSLT for the second case

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="days" match="groupEntry|Details" use="Day"/>

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>ID,Day,Number</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="groupEntry|Details">
      <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('days', Day)[1])">
         <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('days', Day)/Number)"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following results

```
ID,Day,Number
Mon,Mon,-3
111,Mon,-3
Tue,Tue,14
222,Tue,4
444,Tue,5
444,Tue,-3
444,Tue,8
Fri,Fri,-3
333,Fri,-3
```